# Loading data from a Microsoft SQL Server view using ASP.NET Core 3.1 and EF Core

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am loading data from my controller into a html table (view) - approx. 4000 records

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
      var assignments = await _context.myData.ToListAsync();
      return View(myData);
}
```

I then select a record and view the details. All good at this point. I then go back to the index view to look at another record and all the data loads again.

This is not ideal as I have to wait for all the data to load each time before I can view the details of another record. I am wondering how to deal with this. Ideally the table of data will be cached for a period of time before reloading.

Any advice is much appreciated.

Jono

Comment: Don't load everything to begin with. You can't display 4K row in a screen so why read it at all? Read only what you intend to display. *All* web sites use paging or scroll virtualization to avoid loading data they can't display. It's not just a waste of server resources, it makes rendering the page a lot harder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a different style of caching that you could use in your case, below two ways that I could recommend for you:

- you can apply a cache for your action using [ResponseCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/response?view=aspnetcore-5.0) so your can minimize server processing for requests
- you can cache your assignment oject, here is an [example](https://michaelscodingspot.com/cache-implementations-in-csharp-net/) how to do it

Comment: A far better option would be to *not* load data that can't be displayed anyway. Caching would be a great addition but *not* reading 4K rows when only 20 can be displayed is even better

Comment: you are right, but it depends on how he/she is organizing his cshtml,
What I am exposing here are some solutions to inhibit calling his database for each request.

Comment: There's no way one can display 4K rows in a single view, unless one uses a 10m tall display. Caching all 4K rows would waste RAM and the browser would still have problems rendering all of them. Caching is far more efficient once you reduce the amount of data that needs to be cached.

Comment: I have now implemented a jquery data table with paging.  I want to load all the assignments into the grid so the administrator can investigate the data using filtering options. The problem comes when I select an assignment for more details. This action searches the database based on the assignment id and brings back detailed assignment info and displays it in another view page.  When I go back to the index View it loads all the data again. I am only showing  6 columns in the data grid. Assignment Name, subject Name, Teacher, #Students, Date Created, Date Due and an aggregate column.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, he is using jquery datatable, so he is really loading the 4K rows in one shot.
In your case Jono, if you do not want to rewrite your page logic (which I do prefer because I agree with Panagiotis), so you need at least to have a service class that encapsulate the  way you use you assignment list, if you have no choice but loading all the assignment, so I would suggest that you implement data cache, and you can use the cache for both your list and details view

Comment: Thanks to all for advice. I have implemented IMemoryCache and this has resolved my concerns.